# How to fix Interface 'Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface' not found without internet connection?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-6

The former dev seem to have messed composer, and now after I ran `composer dump-autoload` the app was broken.

This is a legacy internal app with no access to the internet so I can't copy files into it.

Now I get the following error:

> Interface 'Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface' not found at
> C:\project\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php

What I know is that all the right files do exist and that this package does work, because whenever I copy the backup vendor folder it working again.

I also have the `"guzzlehttp/guzzle: "^7.2"` in the `require` key of `composer.json`

Although when I run `composer dump-autoload` it does not show `guzzlehttp` in the list of `Discovered packages` (but I'm not sure it's supposed to show it? If yes then it could be related to the problem)

How can I manually fix it without internet connection?

Is it purely `composer` related error and I can try to fix it by editing files in the `vendor/composer` folder? Or I would also need to add some code to the Laravel project itself maybe somewhere in the config files?

**Update 1**: I compared `vendor` folder before and after using `composer dump-autoload` using git, and I found that all the files inside `composer` change, but nothing else.

I then noticed the problematic lines that could cause the issue:

In both `composer/autoload_classmap.php` and `composer/autoload_static.php` the missing `'Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface'` is gone.

Before running the autoload there was this line in `autoload_classmap.php`:

```
'Psr\\Http\\Client\\ClientInterface' => $vendorDir . '/psr/http-client/src/ClientInterface.php'`
```

And this one in `autoload_static.php`:

```
'Psr\\Http\\Client\\ClientInterface' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/psr/http-client/src/ClientInterface.php'`
```

When I added `psr/http-client` to composer.json's `require`, it didn't do anything

**Update 2**: After adding the two missing lines manually to `autoload_static.php` and `autoload_classmap.php`, the package is working adding.

So why does `composer dump-autoload` delete them in the first place? I added `psr/http-client` to `composer.json`. Or maybe that's not enough and there is another package I need to add?

**Update 3**: Could it be related to the composer version? I know that everything was installed using composer 1.x and I ran the `composer dump-autoload` command using composer 2.4

Comment: Why are you reposting the question that asked yesterday?

Comment: I had 2 bad versions of the question and it was confusing after I read them so I made a simplified new one

Answer (score 0):

> **Update 3:** Could it be related to the composer version?

Yes, and also: Composer configuration, environment parameters, command line arguments in use and state of the internet and the Composer cache at the time the related Composer install operation was done (and its associated update operation(s)) and last but not least the state of the vendor folder itself.

All these things are in play when using composer.

This is why projects that you plan to maintain over a longer period of time *should* have a build *and* a development cache *explicitly* rather than only implicitly, as it is easy to loose such information and this can lead to serious errors as you could observe.

Some pointers:

- Consider using a build manager.
- Use artifacts for application deployment (run your application only - not composer - on the target platform).
- Document the target platforms PHP version and configuration.
- Pin the composer version (have all utilities under version control / configuration management you need to develop and maintain the software).
- For long-time projects, have a development and build cache dedicated to the project for composer (as you've learned in the project that you otherwise have no possibility to recreate the state that resulted in your vendor folder production bringing down the whole application).
- Version control is no backup, keep artifacts as the project needs them and backup everything incl. version control system data and tooling configuration as necessary.

And yes, this is easier said than done. But better detect a gap in a build later than not having a build at all.

---

*Earlier:*

1. Put the application under version control *including* the vendor folder (in the form it is working).
2. Checkout that revision on a box where you have internet access.
3. Repair the project.
4. Test the changes and confirm them working for the target platform.
5. Create a new project revision with the changes.
6. Create an artifact out of the new revision.
7. Deploy the artifact on the remote system that has no internet access.
8. Test the changes and confirm them working on the production system.

Comment: The problem is the company policies it is currently not allowed to take it out of the offline environment. But maybe I can do it just before and after the `composer dump-autoload`? Because this is what breaks the app. Without running `composer dump-autoload` the app works fine so maybe I can do the comparison before and after this command.

Comment: I did it, I compared the status of the files using `git` before and after running `composer dump-autoload`, I updated the post if that helps